# hard time with createprocess function

Tags: c, winapi

First off, I've read everything on the net related to this function for a few days but still couldn't get it right. I'm using the same example used in msdn page here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(VS.85).aspx

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    SecureZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    SecureZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\FreeCell.lnk",        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }



    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

As you see i've only changed the directory part. When i run it doesn't give any error but it is also not working.

Comment: In the example the command line is `TCHAR*`. In your code it's `CHAR*`. `CHAR*` passed to `CreateProcessW` results in garbage.

Comment: Are there any compiler warnings? The `CreateProcessW()` version may modifies the second input parameter, which is in this case a string literal (which should be wide string literal if UNICODE is defined).

Comment: Do you definitely provide an argument when you attempt to run it? Even though that argument is unused?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CreateProcess can only start executable programs.  For a .lnk file you'll need help from the shell.  Use [ShellExecuteEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the "open" verb.